# Definition of a gapless spin liquid

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-entanglement, many-body, topological-order

I understand the definition of a gapped spin liquid: it's a gapped, topologically ordered spin state - i.e. there does not exist a local unitary transformation that takes it to a product state in finite time.  I know this is a notoriously difficult question, but what is the precise definition of a gapless spin liquid?  The previous definition no longer works, because almost all gapless states are local unitary inequivalent to a product state.

Comment: You do not need to ask for the definition of a gapless spin liquid. You may just provide your own definition, since the so called non-trivial gapless spin liquid has not been defined.

Comment: Why do you claim that **"all gapless states are local unitary inequivalent to a product state?"**

Comment: **gapless states are many states near the ground state(s), but a product state is just one state.** How do you compare the two by Local-Unitary-Trans?

Comment: @mysteriousness I meant gapless *ground* states.

Comment: @tparker I think a good working definition (at least it fits all examples I know) is: at low energies its effective/universal description is that of a deconfined phase of a massless gauge theory. The 'gauge theory' aspect will results in a local gauge constraint such that the elementary excitations are fractional (e.g., carry gauge charge), and 'deconfined' refers to idea that separating two such fractionalized particles only requires a finite amount of energy. (Note that this definition does not assume the gauge field is gapless such that it also applies to the Kitaev honeycomb model.)

Comment: @RubenVerresen Thanks of the thoughtful comment - I'll be happy to accept if you'd like to convert it to an answer.